# Move File/Folder to a new location and retain its parent folder structure at destination

Tags: bash, unix

Looking for an automated approach (bash script) that can do that following.

I have to move a large number of certain files and folders to a another new location but need to ensure that these files are copied by maintaining its parent folder structure.

## Source

```
Example 1: [primary] > [folder-a] > [folder-a1] > [xyz_out]

Example 2: [primary] > [folder-b] > [folder-b1 ] > a.pdf
```

The folder xyz_1 and the file a.pdf are to be copied to the secondary folder as shown below.

## Destination

Example 1:
    [secondary] > [folder-a] > [folder-a1] > [xyz_out]

Example 2:
    [secondary ] > [folder -b] > [folder_b1 ] > a.pdf

NOTE: The [Primary] location contains lot more files, but I need copy only the xyz_out and a.pdf files. The xyz_out folder is common across many folders in the primary location.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [xyz_out] is a dir you may execute the below command to meet your requirements. Adjust your [primary] and [secondary] directories path accordingly. Use full system path so that you my run this script from anywhere.

For Example : Move Directory Preserving Directory structure

```
find /<fullpath>/[primary]  -type d -name "[xyz_out]" | while     read f
do
     path=$(dirname "$f" | sed -re 's/[primary](\/)?/[secondary] \1/')
     echo "$f -> $path"
     mkdir -p "$path"
     mv "$f" "$path"
done`
```

Example 2: Move file Preserving Directory structure

```
find /<fullpath>[primary]  -type f -name "*.pdf"  | while read f
do
     path=$(dirname "$f" | sed -re 's/[primary](\/)?/[secondary] \1/')
     echo "$f -> $path"
     mkdir -p "$path"
     mv "$f" "$path"
done
```

Comment: Thanks ukrip, let me try that. Appreciate your help.

Comment: thank you for the perfect answer. That really solved the problem.